# Angular: Does it make sense to ever detach the ChangeDetectorRef in onDestroy?

Tags: angular

Does it make sense to ever `onDestroy() {cdr.detach();}`?

We started doing this to every component where ChangeDetectorRef was used, because some bugs occurred at some point in the past and it seemed like a detectChanges() that was triggered before onDestroy, did not get cancelled when the component disappeared (possible in a setTimeout).

But since detaching the ChangeDetectorRef is a common practice on **initialization** followed by manual change detection with `cdr.markForCheck();` or `cdr.detectChanges()`, I assume that detaching does not stop detectChanges or markForCheck and the bug came from somewhere else.

So the only use case where it makes sense to detach the cdr in onDestroy, is when the VIEW and not the CDR itself might trigger a re-render. And since the view is gone when onDestroy is called, this makes no sense altogether.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but we had a situation where a "destroyed" component was still causing issues. It stopped after we unsubscribed from observables/event emitters in onDestroy

Comment: yes we use .takeUntil(this.onDestroy$) too. but we also put cdr in onDestroy, which I think is not necessary. I will remove it and see if there are still bugs. as I wrote in the question, detaching does not seem to cancel a markForCheck or prevent it in the future (if inside a setTimeOut), so it should be pointless (?!)

Comment: markForCheck and detectChanges does not run infinitely. It only runs one time, that is, when its called.Detach is only used whenever you want to stop detectchanges during the change detection tree. Each time you run a detectChanges, it basically cycles through your tree components, up to that component. If you want to stop it before it reaches the end, then you use detach. But it's not something that runs infinity. It runs either when you trigger it or it is trigger by something. So in other words, you don't detach on destroy, you detach during any point of the cycle.